# iPhone 5 Problem with recording on my calender

Tags: iphone

The problem is that I cannot put items on my Calender beyond the date of 29 April 2017... Why can not go to farther years which appear in the calendar

Comment: as far I know it is not the Armageddon day :)

Comment: is it an iCloud calendar, or some other, Google, CalDAV, etc? I have no issue entering dates in 2018 on iCloud, not tested further